# How to expand and collapse tableview cells with dynamic height programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

Here is a video of my problem: https://imgur.com/a/qvGSLfD

My custom cell has 2 labels: one main label, and a subtitle label, both of which are constrained to the cell's contentView layoutMarginsGuide in all directions.

First of all, the whole expand collapse mechanism seems a bit clunky since I'm activating and deactivating constraints and then reloading the indexPaths.

I've tried this approach: When I select the cell, I deactivate the constraints that are responsible for setting only one label and activate the constraints for both, and when it collapses I do the opposite. I feel like this is not a good approach but I was not able to find anything that supported dynamic cell heights.

Basically, I could’ve done something like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex {
        return 200 //Expanded
    }
    return tableView.rowHeight //Not expanded
}
```

but I can't just return the same number for cells that are sized differently.

Here is my tableView code in my viewController class:

```
 var tableView: UITableView = {
    let tv = UITableView(frame: .zero)
    tv.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.reuseIdentifier())
    tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tv.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tv.estimatedRowHeight = 60.0
    tv.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
    tv.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
    tv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    tv.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tv.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    tv.decelerationRate = .fast
    tv.bounces = false
    tv.dataSource = self
    tv.delegate = self
    return tv
}()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.reuseIdentifier(), for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: 99999)
    cell.contentView.bounds = cell.bounds
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.wordLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.wordLabel.frame.width
    cell.descriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = cell.descriptionLabel.frame.width

    //customize this later
    cell.backgroundColor = .white
    cell.set(content: datasource[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.toggle()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Here are the relevant custom Cell functions:

```
var isExpanded: Bool!

private var singleLabelConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!
private var doubleLabelConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]!

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupLabels()
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupLabels()
}

func toggle() {
    isExpanded = !isExpanded
    if isExpanded == false {
        print("collapsed")
        self.descriptionLabel.isHidden = true
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(singleLabelConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(doubleLabelConstraints)
    } else if isExpanded == true {
        print("expanded")
        self.descriptionLabel.isHidden = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(singleLabelConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(doubleLabelConstraints)
    }
}

func setupLabels() {
    isExpanded = false
    descriptionLabel.isHidden = true
    self.contentView.addSubview(wordLabel)
    self.contentView.addSubview(descriptionLabel)

    singleLabelConstraints = [
        wordLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.left
        ),
        wordLabel.topAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.top
        ),
        wordLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.right
        ),
        wordLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.bottom
        )
    ]

    doubleLabelConstraints = [
        wordLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.left
        ),
        wordLabel.topAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.top
        ),
        wordLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.right
        ),

        descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.left
        ),
        descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.wordLabel.bottomAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.top
        ),
        descriptionLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.right
        ),
        descriptionLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor,
            constant: labelInsets.bottom
        )
    ]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(singleLabelConstraints)
}
```

I expected the transition to be smoother and I want something that can easily toggle the cell while keeping the main label in place and just show then subtitle label.

Comment: You are updating constraints for expanding-collapsing which is a bad practice, even you look into console there might be constraint breaks errors.

Comment: @dahiya_boy you're right, I just ended up using a stackview and toggling one of the views because the constraints weren't working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [UIStackView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview) for expand and collapse tableview. You can hide and show the description label when tableview cell is selected.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tv = UITableView(frame: .zero)
        tv.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tv.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tv.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
        tv.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0
        tv.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0
        tv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        tv.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tv.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        tv.decelerationRate = .fast
        tv.bounces = false
        return tv
    }()
    var selectedCell:IndexPath?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["tableView":tableView]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["tableView":tableView]))
    }


}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as? CustomCell ?? CustomCell()
        if let selectedCell = selectedCell, selectedCell == indexPath {
            cell.descriptionLabel.isHidden = false
        } else {
            cell.descriptionLabel.isHidden = true
        }
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedCell = indexPath
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

}

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    let stackView = UIStackView()
    let wordLabel = UILabel()
    let descriptionLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        setupLabels()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupLabels()
    }

    func setupLabels() {

        selectionStyle = .none

        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stackView.spacing = 5
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(stackView)

        wordLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        wordLabel.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lor"
        wordLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        wordLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(wordLabel)

        descriptionLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        descriptionLabel.text = "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
        descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(descriptionLabel)

        wordLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        descriptionLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 30).isActive = true

        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor,constant: 10).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor,constant: 10).isActive = true
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor,constant: 10).isActive = true
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor,constant: 10).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Comment: exactly what I ended up doing and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score -1):

hello there you can overcome the problem by going through this link below,

http://vasundharavision.com/blog/ios/expandable-tableview-without-third-party

i hope it works for you.

Comment: This could be an option as well but since I'm not working with expandable/collapsable collections of items, it's not ideal. I only have one label that I want to show and hide in addition to the main label. See accepted answer.